# Using setTimeout with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, settimeout

I've got some animations that I'm trying to get to work using setTimeouts and for some reason they are firing over and over again until the end of time. I've got a reducer that holds all of my booleans and an action that toggles them, but the problem is that the action is being fired regardless of whether or not the condition is true in the setTimeouts. I've looked in the chrome console and confirmed this to be true, but I don't know why. I'll place my code below.

```
type LandingPagePropTypes = {
  displayCommandText: boolean,
  displayInstallText: boolean,
  displayAboutText: boolean,
  displayEnterText: boolean,
  displayWelcomeHeader: boolean,
  togglePropertyInState: (propertyName: string) => void,
  togglePopUpModal: (message: string) => void,
};

const LandingPage = (
  {
    displayWelcomeHeader,
    displayCommandText,
    displayAboutText,
    displayInstallText,
    displayEnterText,
    togglePropertyInState,
    togglePopUpModal,
  }: LandingPagePropTypes,
) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!displayCommandText) {
      togglePropertyInState('displayCommandText');
    }
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!displayInstallText) {
      togglePropertyInState('displayInstallText');
    }
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!displayAboutText) {
      togglePropertyInState('displayAboutText');
    }
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(() => {
   if (!displayEnterText) {
      togglePropertyInState('displayEnterText');
    }
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!displayWelcomeHeader) {
      togglePropertyInState('displayWelcomeHeader');
    }
  }, 1000);

  return (
    <div className="landing-page-container">
      <MediaQuery maxWidth={767}>
        <MobileLandingPage
          displayWelcomeHeader={displayWelcomeHeader}
        />
      </MediaQuery>

      <MediaQuery minWidth={768}>
        <DesktopLandingPage
          displayCommandText={displayCommandText}
          displayInstallText={displayInstallText}
          displayAboutText={displayAboutText}
          displayEnterText={displayEnterText}
          togglePopUpModal={togglePopUpModal}
        />
      </MediaQuery>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: move your `setTimeout` instructions into  `componentDidMount` method https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: @OlivierBoissé is correct, setTimeout needs to be in the `componentDidMount()` method. Components get rerendered constantly, so you're doing a new setTimeout on each render. You'll also need to a way to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` belongs in the componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate methods. You will also need a `clearTimeout` in the componentWillUnmount method to cancel the timeout or you'll get a `setState on an unmounted component` warning if you unmount the component before the timeout fires. Here's a simplified example.

```
class SomeComp extends Component {
  constructor() {...}

  _startAnimation = timeout => {
    this.enterAnimation = setTimeout(
      () => this.setState({ mode: 'entered' }),
      timeout
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const timeout = someNum

    this._startAnimation(timeout)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    !!this.enterAnimation && clearTimeout(this.enterAnimation)
  }

  render() {...}

}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a shot ASAP. Thank you!

Comment: Remember, if you're doing a setTimeout in componentDidUpdate() you'll need a check to prevent it from firing more than once, e.g. `!this.enterAnimation && this._startAnimation(timeout)`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update on what I ended up doing. I want to add that I'm using Flowtype and eslint paired with AirBnB rules so I had to restructure things a bit to satisfy both of them.

```js
class LandingPage extends Component <LandingPagePropTypes> {
  constructor(props: LandingPagePropTypes) {
    super(props);
    const { togglePropertyInState } = this.props;

    this.setCommandText = setTimeout(() => togglePropertyInState(
      'displayCommandText'
    ), 1000);
    this.setInstallText = setTimeout(() => togglePropertyInState(
      'displayInstallText'
    ), 3000);
    this.setAboutText = setTimeout(() => togglePropertyInState(
      'displayAboutText'
    ), 4000);
    this.setEnterText = setTimeout(() => togglePropertyInState(
      'displayEnterText'
    ), 5000);
    this.setWelcomeHeader = setTimeout(() => togglePropertyInState(
      'displayWelcomeHeader'
    ), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const {
      displayCommandText,
      displayInstallText,
      displayAboutText,
      displayEnterText,
      displayWelcomeHeader,
    } = this.props;

    if (displayCommandText) {
      clearTimeout(this.setCommandText);
    }
    if (displayInstallText) {
      clearTimeout(this.setInstallText);
    }
    if (displayAboutText) {
      clearTimeout(this.setAboutText);
    }
    if (displayEnterText) {
      clearTimeout(this.setEnterText);
    }
    if (displayWelcomeHeader) {
      clearTimeout(this.setWelcomeHeader);
    }
  }

  setCommandText: TimeoutID;

  setInstallText: TimeoutID;

  setAboutText: TimeoutID;

  setEnterText: TimeoutID;

  setWelcomeHeader: TimeoutID;

  render() {
    const {
      displayWelcomeHeader,
      displayCommandText,
      displayAboutText,
      displayInstallText,
      displayEnterText,
      togglePopUpModal,
    } = this.props;


    return (
      <div className="landing-page-container">
        <MediaQuery maxWidth={767}>
          <MobileLandingPage
            displayWelcomeHeader={displayWelcomeHeader}
          />
        </MediaQuery>

        <MediaQuery minWidth={768}>
          <DesktopLandingPage
            displayCommandText={displayCommandText}
            displayInstallText={displayInstallText}
            displayAboutText={displayAboutText}
            displayEnterText={displayEnterText}
            togglePopUpModal={togglePopUpModal}
          />
        </MediaQuery>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```